# Can anyone identify this shower?

Tags: plumbing, shower, valve

Struggling to identify the make and model of my shower which needs a new cartridge.

Distinctive feature is that pipes extend out of the wall and have a blanking plate at the front, with pipes then coming off these into the mixer. This is unlike most others I have seen.

This was in the house when we moved in, going back about 10 years now. Judging by the rest of the bathroom, it won't be a premium brand.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's known as an "exposed thermostatic shower valve", and while I haven't found this exact model, it's very close to the Tre Mercati model shown here: http://www.bakerandsoars.com/store/product_info.php?products_id=7030

Comment: @isherwood Cheers, but as I'm after a replacement part I need the exact make and model. There are many that look similar.